# How would I approach updating all people currently on a page's pages when someone triggers an event?

Tags: ajax, http

For example, someone enters a comment onto a page — how would I cause all other browsers on that page to say reload it to receive the new update? Specifically I am looking at 'dynamically' updating NOT 'periodically' updating. Minimal bandwidth for maximal efficiency.

I am no expert programmer — please simplify the solution if possible.

Comment: What kind of technology are you using ? WCF, ASP.NET,...?

Comment: You have to use more descriptive tags than `update`. What language and technology are you using?

Comment: i am not at that stage yet. i am planning. altho one thing is in java, & i think another component is in jquery(?).

Answer (score 0):

There is [HTTP Server Push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#HTTP_server_push) technology, but from what I heared, I would *always* prefer polling (consumes less server resources and is more compatible).

Comment: i imagine only the minimal amount of updates rather than requiring 1000 per hour or whatever would be better - ? either way, it is not a huge issue just seems way more effective & efficient than periodic polling. to me.

Comment: what is the format of a ircd(?)/irc server? it receives a update, & then distributes it minimally (not thru polling, right?) - that would be the(/a) thing to base it off of.

Comment: or maybe method would be a better word than format. i just mean it's distribution (of information) format. an irc channel would be like a page

Comment: that way it would be instantaneous AND minimal (for bandwidth) & even processing/resources, i would think.

Answer (score 0):

You could use websockets, which are part of HTML5.

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://example.com:8000/websocket.php");
socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
    // update content here
    alert("New content:" + msg);
}
```

However, you would have to have a server-side technology that supports it.